# Using SQLite database for Quiz game

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

For a Quiz game I would like to store the questions in a database containing 7 columns for the Primary key, Question, 4 answers, and the correct answer then run a random method that would pick on of the questions and populate several text fields with the data.

I would then store the value for the "correct answer" column in a variable for a if statement called later on when the user selects an answer.

I have attempted so many tutorials involving SQLite databases that I am very unclear how to do the following:

1. Connect my xcode project to the database (a read-only database stored in the resources folder)
2. Load the database into an object (or load each row at run time at each question to save memory?)
3. Make a method that randomly selects a row, then populates text fields with the data and stores the correct answer column into a variable.

I have been banging my head on my desk for several weeks now, so ANY help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks guys!

Comment: There are lots of good references for using SQLite and I will try to find you one but have you considered core data?

Answer (score 2):

[iPhone Programming Tutorial – Creating a ToDo List Using SQLite Part 1](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/)

[iPhone SDK Tutorial: Reading data from a SQLite Database](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/)

Selecting a Random Row in SQLite

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

And here is [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) and [How to select a random row](http://www.goodhustle.com/blog/2010/04/one-way-to-fetch-a-random-row-from-a-coredata-entity/) if you want to give that a try

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for your quick reply. I've actually gone through both of those tutorials and the first is built around having a database in a tableView that is writable, and the second is based around a TableView application. In both of those tutorials they load the database data into a TableView object with handles all the database rows. I need to be able to specify what row I want to load (which I will do with a random method) then take the information in that rows columns and populate my text fields with it.

Comment: You will retrieve your rows the same as done in the example. Then you will be able to get a string like so `NSString *myQuizQuestion = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]` and display it like this myQuizQuestionLabel.text = myQuizQuestion.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks again for your patience (I'm fairly new in Xcode). I've looked into CoreData as well, its just seems more out of my "relm" of understanding. I think what I'm really looking for is a step by step idea of how to do what I'm looking for, but I can't expect someone (like your self) to take the time to give a complete stranger a detailed step-by-step on how to do this.